# How to iterate over @Model.ICollection in Java Script function?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, icollection

I have a `@Model.LoginCoordinates` where `LoginCoordinates` is `ICollection<Coordinates>`.

The `Coordinates` class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the view in I have:

```
<script>
    function f(){
       for (var i = 0, n  = @Model.LoginCoordinates.Count; i < n; i++) {
                    alert(i);//works fine, I just wanted to check if the loop works at all
       }
    }
</script>
```

It works fine, but instead of that I would like to display all the  do:

```
 <script>
     function f(){
          for (var i = 0, n  = @Model.LoginCoordinates.Count; i < n; i++) {
                  var latitute = @Model.LoginCoordinates[i].Latitude;
                  var longituted = @Model.LoginCoordinates[i].Longitude;
         }
     }
</script>
```

But I cannot access `i` element of the `LoginCoordinates` because it is `ICollection`. Also I believe foreach is impossible at it is c# object.

**Question**: how to iterate over  `ICollection` inside `JavaScript`?

**EDIT**

This above is SSCCE, the real code is;

```
  var map;
    function InitializeMap() {
        alert('works');
        var lat = @Model.LoginCoordinates.First().Latitude;
        var lon = @Model.LoginCoordinates.First().Longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var mapOptions =
        {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); //this breaks the script

    }
    window.addEventListener('load', InitializeMap);
```

Comment: Can I ask what you need to do with this data that it can't be done in the view without javascript?

Comment: @area28 I want to display on google map all coordinates that are in this collection. So I wanted to iterate over it and create marker for every latitude and longitude pair inside that loop.

Comment: I have tried working with a similar data set in a dotnetfiddle and was unable to make it work. A workaround is to put the coords on the DOM somewhere and access them with javascript.

Comment: @area28 Please have a look at my edit. Maybe there is possiblity to pass array of strings to the java script after converting this `ICollection` to the `String[]` inside foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it using `JsonConvert` from newtonsoft.json

```
<script>
var coordinatesJson='@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(Model.LoginCoordinates.ToArray())'

var coordinates=JSON.parse(coordinatesJson);

//you now have coordinates as javascript  object

var map;
function InitializeMap() {
    // could loop over if needed
     for(var coords in coordinates) {
        // do something with coords
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know why for in loop never ends? alerts inside that loop work, but just after it they don't.

Comment: Same if you change it to `for(var i=0;i<coords.length;++i)` ?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention. I changed it to the version you showed in the comment a minute after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<script>
 function f(){
     var coordinates= @Model.LoginCoordinates.ToArray();
     for (var i = 0, n  = coordinates.Length; i < n; i++) {
              var latitute = coordinates[i].Latitude;
              var longituted = coordinates[i].Longitude;
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: i also belive that this is not going to work for you in javascript because you cannot mix your c# code with javascript. ask me again if you did not find your answer yet.

Comment: This line: `var coordinates= @Model.LoginCoordinates.ToArray();` breaks the script, I can't find the exception or compilation error(in chrome console), but alerts inside my function stop working when I add this line.

Comment: Please notice my EDIT in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The Model is only accessible on the server-side as the view is being rendered. Therefore, in order to access its properties on the client-side, you would need to iterate over the collection in C# (razor) and generate HTML that the client-side JavaScript code could then access.

Another alternative would be to create a controller method that returns the model as JSON and call it from the client-side code via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this syntax may be useful to someone:

```
      @section Scripts {
      <script type="text/javascript">  
        @if (Model.LoginCoordinates.Any())
        {
            //C# loop over C# object
            foreach (var point in Model.LoginCoordinates)
            {
                //We are mixing C# and JS code here
                //you could call google's JS API, but still work with C# object properties
                @:console.log(@point.Latitude, @point.Longitude);
            }
        }
      </script>
     }
```